# html5 webcam send last 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, webcam

I'm trying to make a program that keeps continuously the last 5 seconds of recording the webcam (continuos frame recording like security camera). And once you click on a button, send the video to the server (It would be interesting through POST).

Does anyone know what technology I can use? It only occurs to me:

1. Read the camera.
2. Draw it on a canvas.
3. Make a queue with each frame of the canvas where:

   a. If the queue is smaller than 5 seconds, it keeps accumulating.

   b. If the queue is greater than 5 seconds, eliminate each step,
   delete the oldest frame and add the new one.
4. Send the data to server. Can you compress in a video format to save space?
   But the alternative is to send a list of base64 images.

Do you see any other technology better than this? I also have to ensure a camera quality, so streaming is not a solution

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
The problem I have now is that I have an imagedata array, I would like to convert it into a mpeg or some video format to be able to compress it better and send to server.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>

        <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480" style="display: none;"></canvas>

  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var FPS = 5;
var NUM_SECONDS = 5;
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var queue = [];
var enableWrite = true;
// Get access to the camera!
            if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
                // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
          video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    video.play();
          setInterval(function() {getFrame(video); }, 1000/FPS);
          });
            }
function getFrame(video){
  if(!enableWrite) return;
   context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
   if(FPS*NUM_SECONDS <= queue.length){
     queue.shift();
   }
  queue.push(context.getImageData(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height));
}


function save(){
  enableWrite = false;
  var canvasSave = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvasSave.width = canvas.width;
  canvasSave.height = canvas.height;
  var contextSave = canvas.getContent("2d");
  contextSave.drawImage()
  enableWrite = true;

}
```

https://codepen.io/adriaciurana/pen/yqLXMX?editors=0010#0

Comment: I have corrected the question by adding what I currently have, thank you.